# how to use the order by and aggregate function together in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions

```
SELECT
    count(distinct req.requirementid),
    req.requirementid,
    org.organizationid,
    req.locationofposting,
    org.registereddate
FROM OrganizationRegisteredDetails AS org,
    RequirementsDetailsforOrganization AS req
WHERE org.organizationid = req.requirementid
ORDER BY
    org.RegisteredDate desc
```

this shows me the error :

> Column
>   'RequirementsDetailsforOrganization.RequirementID'
>   is invalid in the select list because
>   it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

how to do the 'order by org.RegisteredDate desc' in this Query ....

pls help me out.....??????

Comment: You're trying to count distinct requirementids as well as emitting them in the SELECT list - this isn't going to work.  What would you like the results to look like?

Comment: You're trying to use Count function, so your query needs to be grouped with all fields (group by).

So, what do you want to achieve with the query and the counter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add all columns referenced in the `SELECT` list or in the `ORDER BY` into a `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT 
    count(distinct req.requirementid), 
    req.requirementid, 
    org.organizationid, 
    req.locationofposting, 
    org.registereddate 
FROM OrganizationRegisteredDetails AS org, 
    RequirementsDetailsforOrganization AS req 
WHERE org.organizationid = req.requirementid 
GROUP BY
    req.requirementid, 
    org.organizationid, 
    req.locationofposting, 
    org.registereddate 
ORDER BY 
    org.RegisteredDate desc
```

Although in this case, you'll only get the value 1 in the first column in all rows since you're grouping on req.requirementid!

Comment: +1, just remember that each column returned in the select list must be either an aggergate function call or an item in the GROUP BY list.

Answer (score 1):

Error is there because as per th rule when your using aggregate function with group by clause you have to include the columns which are in your select list

following may help you to achieve functionality you want

```
   (select count(distinct requirementid),requirementid,
     from 
    RequirementsDetailsforOrganization
    group by requirementid) d

    inner join 

    (   SELECT req.requirementid, org.organizationid,

req.locationofposting,org.registereddate FROM OrganizationRegisteredDetails AS org, 

RequirementsDetailsforOrganization AS req WHERE org.organizationid =req.requirementid order by org.RegisteredDate desc) d1
   on 
    d.requirementid= d1.requirementid
```